# Смысл ссылок в методах функций C++

Tags: c++, ссылки, перегрузка-операторов, оператор-присваивания

Всем привет, я начинающий в C++, возник вопрос касательно смысла ссылок в методе функции.
Есть класс MyString, в нём два private поля: st - char массив и size - длина массива. Вот я делаю перегрузку оператора =

```
MyString & operator =(MyString & tmp)
```

Зачем ставится ссылка в аргументе я знаю, это указание системе, что нужно не копировать объект, а взять его адрес. Но что значит & перед operator? В каких случаях нужно использовать?

Comment: Амперсанд (`&`) относится не к `operator =`, а к `MyString`. То есть возвращаемый тип — тоже ссылка.

Answer (score 4):

Ссылками могут быть не только параметры, но и возвращаемые значения.

Во-первых, такое определение перегруженного оператора присваивания согласуется с требованием для встроенных операторов присваивания согласно стандарту C++ (5.18 Assignment and compound assignment operators)

> 1 The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators
>   all group right-to-left. All require a modiﬁable lvalue as their left
>   operand and **return an lvalue referring to the left operand**...

Во-вторых, Это позволяет избежать копирования исходного объекта в качестве возвращаемого значения, для которого было выполнено присвоение.  То есть оператор возвращает ссылку на свой левый операнд (`MyString &`).

В-третьих, это позволяет записывать такие конструкции как, например,

```
MyString a, b, c;
(a = b ) += c;
```

Имейте в виду, что объявленный таким образом оператор присваивания

```
MyString & operator =(MyString & tmp);
```

не сможет иметь дело с константными или временными объектами в качестве правого операнда, так как параметр оператора объявлен как не константная ссылка, которую нельзя привязывать к временным объектам.

Более универсальный подход - это объявить оператор как

```
MyString & operator =(const MyString & tmp);
```

Comment: Вместо ссылки можно также испльзовать указатель. Но все-таки использование ссылки целесообразнее. А почему?

Comment: @stan Вы про какую ссылку в данном случае? Параметр или возвращаемое значение?

Comment: @CITBL возвращаемое значение

Comment: @Stan Мы хотим сделать наш оператор присваивания похожим на встроенный оператор присваивания. А встроенный позволяет такие штуки: `a=b=c=d;` Конечно, такое тоже можно реализовать даже если возвращаемое значение - указатель. Но тогда и параметр метода оператора тоже должен быть указателем. Но мы-то хотим присваивать переменной типа MyString другую переменную типа MyString а не указатель на MyString. Хотя чисто технически ничто нам не мешает сделать оператор присвоения указателя или вообще чего угодно.

Answer (score 4):

`&` относится к типу возвращаемого результата. В данном случае означает, что возвращается ссылка на `MyString`. Оператор присвоения в С/С++ должен возвращать результат присвоения, который равен значению переменой слева от `=` после присвоения. Можно возвращать и копию результата, то есть без ссылки, но это может быть неэффективнее, если результат содержит много данных.

Важно отметить, что если возвращаешь ссылку, то эта ссылка должна быть на что-то, что будет продолжать жить после выхода из кода оператора. (Обычно, конечно, операторы присвоения возвращают ссылку на `*this`, то есть на сам объект от имени которого вызывается оператор - тот объект который слева от = ).

Кстати, некоторые рекомендуют возвращать константную ссылку:

```
const MyString& operator=(const MyString& tmp);
```

чтобы нельзя было писать такие вещи:

```
(a=b)=c;
```

Потому что после выполнения такого выражения, `b` будет не равно `a` и `c`, если изначально `b` было не равно `c`. Считается что это выглядит не интуитивно понятно. Но это необязательно. Например многие популярные библиотеки классов так не делают.

Comment: Это совершенно неправильное объявление оператора присваивания, так как меняется статус объекта из неконстантного в константный. Рассмотрите к примеру функцию void f( MyString & ); и вызов ее с выражением f( left = right );  Компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке, так как неожиданно lvalue превратилось в const lvalue. Поэтому я не знаю, кто так рекомендует объявлять оператор присваивания, когда это противоречит его описанию в стандарте, ссылку на которое я дал в своем ответе.

Comment: То есть в результате вы не только объявляете оператор присваивания, но и оператор преобразования, выполняющий функцию преобразования, соответствующую const_cast. То есть ваш оператор присваивания имеет неуместный побочный эффект..

Comment: @VladfromMoscow согласен, меняет на константную ссылку. Но мы не обязаны переопределять оператор присвоения для своих классов, так чтобы он вёл себя в точности так же, как он ведет себя со встроенными типами. Конечно, если делаешь какую-то библиотеку классов, то очень желательно следовать стандартному поведению оператора =. Тогда надо обязательно возвращать ссылку, и эта ссылка должна быть неконстантной.

Comment: Это как раз делает такой оператор, который выбивается из общего определения и имеет побочные эффекты, интуитивно непонятным, и может привести к возникновению ошибок в программе, когда меняется статус ссылки.

Comment: Например, если вы определили составной оператор присваивания с константной возвращаемой ссылкой, то такой вызов функции f( true ? a += b : c ); приведет к ошибке компиляции, если функция принимает не константную ссылку в качестве аргумента, так как тип возвращаемого значения тернарного оператора будет константная ссылка.  Каждый оператор должен делать ту вещь, для чего он предназначен. Не следует включать в определение операторов побочные эффекты.